# Can calls to memory allocation and constructor be interleaved with other operations required to perform a "new" expression?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, new-operator

Suppose I have a following class:

```
 class Sample {
 public:
     Sample( int ) {}
 };
```

some function returning an `int`

```
int SomeFunction()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and this code:

```
Sample* sample = new Sample( SomeFunction() );
```

Now I expect the following sequence:

- `SomeFunction()` is run, then
- `::operator new()` is run to allocate memory for the object, then
- `class Sample` constructor is run over allocated memory

Is this order fixed or can it be changed by an implementation such that say first memory is allocated, then `SomeFunction()` is called, then constructor is run? In other words, can call to `operator new()` function and call to class constructor be interleaved with anything?

Comment: one thing is surely specified that `SomeFunction()` will be called always before constructor `Sample()`. So question will narrow down only between `SomeFunction()` and `operator new`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order is unspecified. [5.3.4]/21 reads:

> Whether [operator new] is called
>   before evaluating the constructor
>   arguments or after evaluating the
>   constructor arguments but before
>   entering the constructor is
>   unspecified. It is also unspecified
>   whether the arguments to a constructor
>   are evaluated if [operator new]
>   returns the null pointer or exits
>   using an exception.

Comment: +1: The only thing that must hold is that the allocation function must return before the constructor is called.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: True. In fact the only possible sequences (assuming new doesn't throw) are: a) operator new, SomeFunction(), Sample ctor b) SomeFunction(), operator new, Sample ctor

Answer (score 2):

The order of the calls to operator new and SomeFunction is unspecified - so it may change based on optimisation settings, compiler version, etc.

The constructor call I think has to come last.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could be interleaved.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int i)
    {
        cout << "constructor" << endl;
    }
    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        cout << "new" << endl;
        return malloc(size);
    }
    void operator delete(void*, size_t)
    {
        cout << "delete" << endl;
    }
};

int f()
{
    cout << "f()" << endl;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    A* a = new A(f());
}

Output:
new
f()
constructor
```

Though not guaranteed by the standard, compilers do have a reason to allocate memory first. If memory allocation fails, the constructor won't be called at all. So evaluating constructor arguments too early is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Which compiler does it happen with?

Comment: You could just as well say that if the argument evaluation throws an exception, then the constructor won't be called at all, and so calling `new` too early is a bad idea!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what I think happens is:

- new is used to allocate raw memory
- SomeFunction() is called  returning a value X
- the constructor is called, with X as a a parameter

but I could be wrong. I would say that this shows that you shouldn't be worrying about the order.

Comment: Except the order of the first two bullet points could be reversed. There would be reason to worry about order if SomeFunction returned a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, in which case the code should be rewritten for exception-safety.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change what happens when you run that line of code. You can run some different lines of code.

```
void * p = ::operator new (sizeof (SomeFunction));
SomeFunction temp;
SomeFunction* sample = new (p) SomeFunction(temp);
```